# 8 relay Board como puedo hacer un programa para controlarla

Tags: java, python, c

Tengo esta caja de reles llamada 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/SainSmart-8-channel-12-V-USB-Relay-Module-Opto-couple-For-Arduino-Robotics-/271052850490

Lo que quiero y pretendo es poder realizar un programa en python o java que se conecte con ella por un puerto com y active y desactive los reles ¿Esto es posible?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje de programación quieres trabajar en [tag:java], en [tag:python] on en [tag:c]? Cada lenguaje aportará una solución totalmente diferente.

Comment: Se puede hacer en cualquier lenguaje, ahora que aquí no te vamos a decir como hacerlo desde cero, sino que te ayudaremos cuando te atasques en algun punto en concreto.

Comment: mira los ejemplos en http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples.htm